# Help identifying tantalum capacitor marked E105

Tags: capacitor, identification, markings, tantalum

I am trying to repair a device that was handed to me. It has a broken tantalum capacitor with a missing lead, so it needs replacement. However I'm having trouble identifying its capacitance, voltage etc. I believe it's a KEMET T494 series but I can't say for sure. The markings on the capacitor are 'E105'. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: photo of capacitor]

Comment: I would guess a 1uF 25v polarised capacitor

Comment: What makes you think it is Kemet T494? That's a low ESR series, meaning it would be a specialized cap. Also, nothing of these markings is remotely near the Kemet ones.

Comment: @Lundin I thought the 'O' like marker on the polarity stripe looked like the one that the T494 series have according to [this](http://alasir.com/reference/kemet_tantalum_capacitors/) site but since I'm not really familiar with other manufacturers I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"105" usually means 10 pF x 100000. The "5" parts represents the number of zeros in the multiplier. "104" would be 100 nF. "103" would be 10 nF and "102" would be 1 nF.

Many companies use "E" to symbolize 25 volts and, as an example I've seen "A" used to represent 4.0 volts, B to represent 6.3 volts, C to represent 10 volts, D to represent 15 (or sometimes 16) volts hence, E represents 25 volts.

But, there are other code systems for the capacitor's voltage rating such as this: -

[image]

However, and luckily, E represents 25 volts in both systems. Another system that also uses "E" to represent 25 volts: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The voltage seems to check out with some different tantalum caps on the same trace which where rated for 25V as well (Larger case-size so hence better markings).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Tantalum Poly Cap and the E would be 25V and the 105 would be 10+5 Zeros in pF or 1uF. The circle seems to indicate Kemet. Here is a snip from a similar Vishay Cap.

[image]