# What do these capacitor markings mean?

Tags: capacitor, components, surface-mount, markings

I think the two cans in the two photos below are aluminum electrolytic capacitors (the top photo is much more zoomed in, but the capacitors are about the same physical size),
probably from the same manufacturer.

I guess the top one is 47uF and the bottom one is 4.7uF, and I guess the swirly triangle in the top one is the manufacturer's logo (but I don't recognize it).

Can someone explain all the markings here?  Does "2AV" mean that the capacitor allows up to 200V?

[image: 47 uF]

[image: 4.7 uF]

Comment: 2A is probably 100V, see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458090/311631

Comment: What does that "swirly triangle" mean?  I found it in one more place and feel like I'm close to cracking the code.  https://www.amazon.com/jujinglobal-10pcs-Aluminum-electrolytic-Capacitor/dp/B09MWB45NR

Comment: Nice find. Probably a no-name logo, then. I don't recognize it offhand. Name in the link seems to be a dead end, at least on EN search, but that's not too surprising as such sellers frequently pop up overnight, hock a bunch of stuff under a random name, then disappear as suddenly as they came.